# Making a dataframe in R from multiple rowMeans

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have not so much experience in R. So in my case though, I have a dataframe with gene names and their expression in different tissues (tissue e.g. RAM,SAM etc) (3 replicates for every tissue - RAM1, RAM2, RAM3) (DeSEQ2 package result).Looks like this:

```
                      RAM1    RAM2       RAM3       SAM1      SAM2.....
gene.01G000150   3.112134   0.00000   0.00000   7.5206516 1.252147 
.....
```

So I want to calculate the mean for every tissue and then build a new dataframe with the means this time. What I have already tried is the following.

Desired output: A table like the following:

```
                RAM(mean)   SAM(mean)....
gene.01G000150   5.578          3.5...
...
```

Do you now any efficient and reproducible way to do it?

update: This function seems to do the trick:
`check_genes$SAM <-apply(check_genes[c("SAM1", "SAM2","SAM3")], MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) mean(x[x!=0]))`
but you have to do it individually for every replicate you possess.

Comment: Thanks for you reply but this doesn't seem to work. This time instead of a column of values it prints a row of values.

Comment: Some friendly advice for future questions. You're more likely to get help if you provide a fully reproducible example -- [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) is really helpful for this. Your question should include code + data + desired/expected result + errors/actual result. This way, we can run the code on the data and demonstrate how to fix your problems.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly -- a big if! -- you want the mean expression for each tissue/gene combination, right? So, you want the mean of the three runs for,

- RAM-gene.01G000150
- SAM-gene.01G000150
- FEC-gene.01G000150
- ...

and so on for other genes and tissues, too? If so, I'd restructure the data first to make life easier. You don't include a dataset I can use for demo purposes, so I constructed a dummy one.

```r
# Load the library
library(data.table)

# Dummy data
dt <- data.table(genes = letters[1:5],
                 RAM1 = runif(5),
                 RAM2 = runif(5),
                 RAM3 = runif(5),
                 SAM1 = runif(5),
                 SAM2 = runif(5),
                 SAM3 = runif(5))

#    genes      RAM1       RAM2      RAM3      SAM1       SAM2       SAM3
# 1:     a 0.7063121 0.43993347 0.6226666 0.8476453 0.05446956 0.44600060
# 2:     b 0.4897803 0.50044643 0.1632004 0.1464797 0.43376887 0.27821878
# 3:     c 0.9418203 0.67954434 0.2502699 0.5309522 0.48029960 0.82622447
# 4:     d 0.3498353 0.81831758 0.8970066 0.9042565 0.25258854 0.09807793
# 5:     e 0.2324447 0.06337947 0.7269116 0.5776730 0.37568198 0.68405615
```

Next, I transform the data from wide to long format:

```r
# From wide to long format
dt_l <- melt(dt, id.vars = "genes", variable.name = "tissue_run", value.name = "expression")

#    genes tissue_run expression
# 1:      a       RAM1 0.70631211
# 2:      b       RAM1 0.48978034
# 3:      c       RAM1 0.94182026
# 4:      d       RAM1 0.34983529
# 5:      e       RAM1 0.23244474
# 6:      a       RAM2 0.43993347
# 7:      b       RAM2 0.50044643
# 8:      c       RAM2 0.67954434
# 9:      d       RAM2 0.81831758
# 10:     e       RAM2 0.06337947
# 11:     a       RAM3 0.62266657
# 12:     b       RAM3 0.16320043
# 13:     c       RAM3 0.25026990
# 14:     d       RAM3 0.89700660
# 15:     e       RAM3 0.72691159
# 16:     a       SAM1 0.84764528
# 17:     b       SAM1 0.14647973
# 18:     c       SAM1 0.53095222
# 19:     d       SAM1 0.90425646
# 20:     e       SAM1 0.57767296
# 21:     a       SAM2 0.05446956
# 22:     b       SAM2 0.43376887
# 23:     c       SAM2 0.48029960
# 24:     d       SAM2 0.25258854
# 25:     e       SAM2 0.37568198
# 26:     a       SAM3 0.44600060
# 27:     b       SAM3 0.27821878
# 28:     c       SAM3 0.82622447
# 29:     d       SAM3 0.09807793
# 30:     e       SAM3 0.68405615
# genes tissue/run expression
```

Finally, I split the tissue/run number variable into its components (i.e., tissue and run number), I group by tissue and gene, then I take the mean of the replicates.

```r
# Split into tissue and replicate number
dt_l[, replicate := gsub(".*([0-9]+)$", "\\1", tissue_run)
     ][, tissue := gsub("^(.*)[0-9]+$", "\\1", tissue_run)
       ][, .(mean = mean(expression)), by = c("tissue", "genes")]

#     tissue genes      mean
# 1:     RAM     a 0.5896374
# 2:     RAM     b 0.3844757
# 3:     RAM     c 0.6238782
# 4:     RAM     d 0.6883865
# 5:     RAM     e 0.3409119
# 6:     SAM     a 0.4493718
# 7:     SAM     b 0.2861558
# 8:     SAM     c 0.6124921
# 9:     SAM     d 0.4183076
# 10:    SAM     e 0.5458037
```

Is this the desired output?

---

In light of the updated question, a final step is needed:

```r
dt_l_s <- dt_l[, replicate := gsub(".*([0-9]+)$", "\\1", tissue_run)
               ][, tissue := gsub("^(.*)[0-9]+$", "\\1", tissue_run)
                 ][, .(mean = mean(expression)), by = c("tissue", "genes")]

dcast(dt_l_s, genes ~ tissue)

# Using 'mean' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
#    genes       RAM       SAM
# 1:     a 0.5896374 0.4493718
# 2:     b 0.3844757 0.2861558
# 3:     c 0.6238782 0.6124921
# 4:     d 0.6883865 0.4183076
# 5:     e 0.3409119 0.5458037
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works for me at least for the `dt_l <- melt...` then I encounter some errors either with the `tissue_run` or the `:=`. I have edited my question, and I have included a desired output.

Comment: @gforg34 can you be more specific about what the errors you encounter are?

Comment: I get this error: ``Error in `:=`(replicate, gsub(".*([0-9]+)$", "\\1", variable.name)) : 
  could not find function ":="`` .I made a search about this assignment operator and I found that you can use instead "<-". If I do it then I encounter: another error ``Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'gsub': object 'variable.name' not found``

Comment: @gforg34 Did you load the `data.table` library?

Comment: Oh this is something that I forgot to do. Now that I did it though I have another error. ``Error in `:=`(replicate, gsub(".*([0-9]+)$", "\\1", tissue_run)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").``

Comment: @gforg34 The error message asks that you check if `is.data.table(DT) == TRUE`. In other words, are you performing the operation on a data table? You'll notice in my code I use a data table to define the data structure. If you're not, you can use `setDT(df)` to convert `df` into a data table.

Comment: Okay, done with this too. Sorry for the repeated errors and questions but thanks for your patience. Because I hardly understand what is going on with the code, it is quite advanced for me. Because now I am facing another problem. ``Error in `[.data.table`(dt_l[, `:=`(replicate, gsub(".*([0-448]+)$", "\\1",  : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length(s) (448,14). Each must be length 448; the same length as there are rows in x (after subsetting if i is provided).``  As far as I understand the length of my data.table is 448, but then I dont get the issue here

Comment: @gforg34 it's difficult to resolve without seeing the data, but I expect you wouldn't want to make it public. Perhaps you could share the structure (i.e., genes, columns) but fill it with random values (e.g.,  using `runif`)? If so, you can edit the question and post the data there. `dput` is useful for outputting data in a format that can be copy and pasted.

Comment: Sorry for this late message. I tried what you proposed to do with the ``runif``, and it worked for the random values, still though for my actual data that wasn't the case. There was an extra column there which I assume affect the process. But I appreciate your help. I can share my results in my question. However, I also found another function that does the trick ``check_genes$SAM <-apply(check_genes[c("SAM1", "SAM2","SAM3")], MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) mean(x[x!=0]))
``. The only problem is that you have to do it for every column independently.